# How a 10GB network can copy 1TB data in 2 hours?

Tags: computer-networks

In the slides of a university lecture, the following phrase got my attention.

> Assuming 10GB network, it takes 2 hours to copy 1TB.

My calculation was as follows.

> 10GB network = 10 gigabits per second network = 10 x 10^9 bits per
> second ------> (1)
> 1TB = 10^3 x 10^9 x 8 bits --------------> (2)
>
> Then the time to copy 1TB data = (2) / (1) = 8 x (10^12) / (10^10) =
> 800s = 13.33 minutes

I'm not getting 2 hours as the result of the above calculation, seems like I have got something wrong.
Can someone please educate me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect this will be considered off-topic. However, 133 minutes is close to 2 hours, so perhaps the slides mistakenly calculated for 1 Gbps, not 10.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought this was off-topic, but had nowhere to post this. Maybe the slides have mistakenly calculated for 1Gbps, as you stated. Thanks for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hard drives capable of reading /writing 140 Megabytes per second, then it takes about 2 hours with a 10 Gbit network to copy one terabyte. 140 MB per second sounds reasonable. A 1 Gbit network wouldn’t take much longer, but then we’d need to know all the overheads in much more detail for precise answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have just done the calculation with the raw data to be transferred and not taken into account of the overhead of transferring data using networking protocols across any particular  network. Almost no networking technology transfers data without an overhead because there is the need for addressing the data, routing the data, dealing with the reliability of the network and so forth.

If we assume a layered packet-switching protocol network, such as the internet, we have many layers, each with its own overhead. Each overhead adds more bytes to the data to be transferred.

<kbd>Physical Layer Overhead

 <kbd>Datalink Layer Overhead

 <kbd>Network Layer Overhead (IP)

 <kbd>Transport Layer Overhead (TCP)

 <kbd>Application Layer Overhead

 <kbd>The file

 <kbd>The data</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Getting a large amount of data from one place to another reliabily on a packet-switching network has quite a large overhead.

Comment: 90% overhead seems excessive, though.

Comment: Yes. As any network engineer will tell you, assuming full duplex, no contention, no retransmission, no jumbo frames, and TCP, then the maximum throughput of wired ethernet is 90% of the bit rate, or 10% overhead. This is a very reliable rule of thumb.

(Note that the rated "speed" of wired ethernet is the bit rate, not the baud rate; 10Gb ethernet means 10Gb raw bit rate, but the clock is actually 12.5Gb/s to account for line coding.)